# NumberFormatException when parsing String to Float value

Tags: java, parsing, generics, interface, java.lang.class

```
System.out.println("Enter a number: ");

String in1 = input.nextLine();

Integer input1 = Integer.valueOf(in1);
Float input2 = Float.parseFloat(in1);
Double input3 = Double.valueOf(in1).doubleValue();

System.out.println();
System.out.println("Enter another number: ");

String in2 = input.nextLine();
Integer input21 = Integer.valueOf(in2);
Float input22 = Float.parseFloat(in2);
Double input23 = Double.valueOf(in2).doubleValue();

FloatN fco = new FloatN();

System.out.println();
System.out.println("The sum of both of your numbers is: " + fco.add(input2, input22));
done = true;
```

I'm well aware that this program is completely impractical, I only wrote it to practice parsing, generics, and interfaces. I tried Integer, which worked fine, but upon trying the Float and Double.add() functions, I get 3 errors:

at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString

at java.lang.Integer.parseInt

at java.lang.Integer.valueOf

I removed the Integer parsers, and the program worked fine. I'm confused as to why I get the errors only when I enter Decimal values and would like someone to help point out what exactly is causing the exception so I can avoid any errors like this in the future, and since removing the Integer parser removes any functionality from the IntegerN class.

Also, if anyone needs the FloatN class for whatever reason:

```
public static class FloatN implements Summization<Float>{
    public FloatN(){}
    public Float add(Float a, Float b)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
}
```

Summization is a generic interface with an add() method.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My input is 5, 7 when testing the IntegerN object, and 7.5, 8.0 when testing FloatN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you enter a decimal value as input, `Integer.parseInt()` method won't be able to parse it. If you still want to have them all in your code, you have to get int value of that `Float` value. You can use `intValue()` method:

```
    Float input2 = Float.parseFloat(in1);
    Integer input1 = Integer.valueOf(input2.intValue());
```

Comment: Ahhh I understand. So all Integers are floats, but not all floats are Integers, so when I use the valueOf for Integer to parse the String, it tries to read a float, but it can't, but the Float parser and Double parser can read each other (up to a certain point). Alright I get it now, thank you all for your help. I guess I'll have to remember that Float and Double can read Integer, but not the other way around

Answer (score 1):

becuase `Integer.valueOf(in2);` this line will give NumberFormatException with `float` and `double` you can use

```
Number num = NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(myNumber);
```

see @ http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html

Answer (score 1):

Maybe add string which is not contain a parsable float or it is null.

[From javadoc:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat%28java.lang.String%29)

```
NullPointerException - if the string is null
NumberFormatException - if the string does not contain a parsable float.
```

Answer (score 0):

The NumberFormatException comes in the Integer parser, and not in the Double and Float parsers if input contains decimal.

In such situations, you can get the the integer part of the decimal number using [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) and parse:

```
    String[] s = in1.split("\\.");
    Integer input1 = Integer.valueOf(s[0]);
    Float input2 = Float.parseFloat(in1);
    Double input3 = Double.valueOf(in1).doubleValue();
```