# Android: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "27.0"

Tags: java, android, integer, numberformatexception, numberpicker

I haven't found an answer to this question where the decimal is 0, so...

```
//Value of row.get(2) = "27.0"

private NumberPicker numEntry;
numEntry.setMaxValue(40);
numEntry.setMinValue(15);
numEntry.setValue(Integer.valueOf(row.get(2)));
```

Error message:

```
05-27 14:30:51.576  10143-10143/com.exampleapp.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "27.0"
```

I've tried a few different methods to convert the string "27.0" into an integer 27, Math.floor, parseInt... the ArrayList row is pulled from the web via html so it starts life as a string, fyi.

How do I set the NumberPicker to this initial value?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would just do

```
(int)Double.parseDouble(row.get(2));
```

so it will be

```
numEntry.setValue((int)Double.parseDouble(row.get(2)));
```

it will handle double, integers and so on. Will throw `NumberFormatException` only if it's a non valid number.

You should only worry about the fact that a double could not fit in a int. But i don't think it's a problem here.

Answer (score 5):

I think that you can use the **java.text.NumberFormat** class:

```
Number num = NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(row.get(2));
int desiredInt = num.intValue();
```

Comment: Surround it with a try catch block to catch ParseException. This is the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just try this code from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20537121/numberformatexception-when-parsing-string-to-float-value/20537324#20537324):

```
    NumberPicker numEntry;
    numEntry.setMaxValue(40);
    numEntry.setMinValue(15);
    Float input2 = Float.parseFloat("27.0");
    numEntry.setValue(input2.intValue());
```

And I get `27` as integer. Here you have a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: valueOf(String) also takes a string, so this is not correct. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/number_valueof.htm

Comment: Yes sorry, I didn't see the 27.0 was a String,. I am updating my answer

Comment: @Scott Updated, check if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a string("27.0") to integer convert that string to integer

int foo = Integer.parseInt("1234");

valueOf that you used in question  uses parseInt internally. The difference is parseInt returns an int primitive while valueOf returns Integer

Comment: As I mentioned on the question, I tried parseInt.  Also Integer.valueOf should return an Integer.

Comment: Actually, valueOf uses parseInt internally. The difference is parseInt returns an int primitive while valueOf returns Integer